# How to find last 10 years using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an sql query where i have to find last 10 years. Suppose this is 2015 then then the query should return 2015,2014,2013... and so on. For this i have used the following query-

```
select top 10 DATEPART(Year,getdate()) order by DATEPART(Year,getdate()) desc
```

But the above query is returning only single query which is the current year. Please help me someone here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
with yearlist as 
(
    select (DATEPART(Year,getdate())-10) as year
    union all
    select yl.year + 1 as year
    from yearlist yl
    where yl.year + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)

select year from yearlist order by year desc;
```

Comment: As I think this query will return data for last 11 year.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas I have checked it in sql query and this query is returning 10 years.

Comment: 2015
2014
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007
2006
2005, seems like 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can do It in following:

```
DECLARE @YearsToPass INT

SET @YearsToPass = 10

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DATEPART(YY, GETDATE())- @YearsToPass + 1 as Years
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Years + 1 as Years
    FROM cte 
    WHERE Years + 1 <= YEAR(GETDATE()) 
)

SELECT Years 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY Years DESC
```

Simple set `@YearsToPass` to number of how many years you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

FYI For a non-CTE approach....

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year,DateAdd(Year,-I,getdate()))
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS I UNION
    SELECT 1 AS I UNION
    SELECT 2 AS I UNION
    SELECT 3 AS I UNION
    SELECT 4 AS I UNION
    SELECT 5 AS I UNION
    SELECT 6 AS I UNION
    SELECT 7 AS I UNION
    SELECT 8 AS I UNION
    SELECT 9 AS I UNION
    SELECT 10 AS I 
) AS T
```

stats for this

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   4 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (11 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

VS stats for CTE

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   3 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (11 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads
>   67, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 3 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.